# How to use radio button list control

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I believe there is a  **radio button list control**  while developing  **web pages using asp.net**  but not while developing a  **windows form**.

I am developing a windows form where I need to check the user's gender, weather male or female.

Right now I am setting a global check variable and set it when the button is selected like shown below.

I have placed them within a panel:

```
Private Sub rbtMale_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtMale.CheckedChanged

gender = "Male"

End Sub

Private Sub rbtFemale_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbtFemale.CheckedChanged

gender = "Female"

End Sub
```

Is there any other better way of doing this check?

Comment: Hope I have made my question clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a *group* using *container* control (`Panel` or `GroupBox`). Add `Radio` buttons inside the *container* so when the user selects one radio button within a group, the others *clear* automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this one?

[image: Radio Buttons]

Radio Buttons are available in `WinForms`.

Comment: Pretty sure that the RadioButton control is also available in WebForms, which is what he's asking about.

Comment: @CodyGray the way he is constructing his question sounds he was asking for WinForms when he says "...but not while developing a windows form". I could misunderstood him though as you were saying here.

Comment: I am developing a windows form and thanks a lot I got the answer